# Add last hour mean to every sample of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, feature-engineering

As I wrote in the title, given a pandas dataframe with multiple features and with granularity per minute I want to add as new features the mean of last 1 hour for every minute.

How I can do this?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

date_today = datetime.datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + datetime.timedelta(10), freq='T')
data=[]
for i in range(3):
    np.random.seed(seed=i)
    data.append(np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days)))
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': days, 'feature1': data[0],'feature2': data[1],'feature3': data[2]})
df = df.set_index('Datetime')
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x.replace(second=0,microsecond=0))
```

So now I want to add for every feature in df add the mean of the last 60 minutes dropping the data where is impossible to calculate that mean.

Any tips will be so appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution in my opinion:

Starting from example:

```
df_new=df.rolling('1h').mean()
df_final=pd.merge(df, df_new, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df_final[60:-1]
```

Comment: There is any way of select the last hour from the index instead of taking 60 observations writing something like .loc['1h'] ???

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

As in your comment, you are asking for a mean for each row computed over the previous 60 rows. This means a rolling window.

The following loop would do that:

```
rolling_avg = pd.DataFrame(columns=['f1', 'f2', 'f3'])

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if i<60: print(i, df.index[i], str('computation previous 60 minutes not possible'))
    else: rolling_avg.loc[i] = list(df.iloc[i-60:i,[0,1,2]].mean())
```

Finally, the expected outcome:

```
rolling_avg

f1  f2  f3
60  48.733333   45.083333   54.433333
61  49.316667   45.150000   54.483333
62  48.600000   46.316667   54.766667
..  ..          ..          ..
```

This solution is rather slow, though with your data size doable.
For larger data it would be nice to have a faster solution.

Comment: Hi ty for your reply, but I want to obtain for every sample of the data frame (every raw) the mean of the last 60 minutes dropping the first 59 elements where is not possible obtain that mean

Comment: Ok this Is right i can fix and add the new features to the old dataframe, regarding Speed how i can improve?